# Upgrading JQuery version from 1.4.2 to 1.11.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to upgrade JQuery version that I am using in the project from **1.4.2** to **1.11.3**. Some of the functions and attributes I am using at the moment are as following.

```
.ready() 
.show()
.hide()
.focus()
.blur()
.submit()
.click()
.change()
.attr() - both setter and getter 
.append()
.html() - both setter and getter 
.on(trigger,function(){})
.val() - both setter and getter 
$('#elemId').removeClass("error").next("em").text("");
.removeAttr()
.css()
.text()
.addClass("error")
.height()
.is(‘:visible’)
$('#elemId').not('.checkrepeat').html("");
$('#elem').offset().top;  
.detach();
$('#tabBox-bd').find('.con').eq(i).detach();

.length
```

Can someone let me know if any of these methods would not work for the new version (1.11.3) that I will be using. It's not that I will be just sitting back and wait for your answer. I will also be changing the version in many places in the project and doing testing. I just hoped that anyone of you have already being through a similar process and have any tips. Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: for checking that you have release notes attached each release which says what has changed in that version

Comment: all those methods are fine.

Comment: You have enumerated all basic functions of jQuery. I am working with jQuery 2.1.3 and I use all of these functions in my code. That's why I may suggest that all of them should work in jQuery 1.11.3. Why don't you just change jQuery, run every page and check for console errors?

Comment: .attr might have issues depending on how you used it. If used to access properties, .prop should be used instead. There's a great SO post that goes into detail about the .attr and .prop change

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, yes. I am going through each pages now. Just wanted some opinions to cover all areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all functions will work in jquery version 1.4.2.

If in case you find any problem then you can use jquery migrate  plugin for fallback so all previous version's functionality will work as it is .

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme